# HTTPful request with json body returns error 400

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-web-api2, httpful

I have this code :

```
$arr = array("id" => 3);

$response = \Httpful\Request::get($restapiUrl)
            ->sendsJson()
            ->expectsJson()
            ->body(json_encode($arr))
            ->send();
```

Every call to my API ends in failure with error 404 : Bad request. I have to send parameters through the request body from php.

My api code :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MyController/GetProduct")]
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct([FromBody] int id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(product);
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: your controller expects an `int` which isn't an object

Comment: You are totally rigth! Thank you!